# Can I convert Cakewalk .wrk files to MIDI?

Tags: midi

I have a bunch of .wrk files from when I owned a couple of Cakewalk programs. I don't have any of my Cakewalk software anymore, though. Is there any way I can open the files up or convert them to MIDI without buying new software?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.wrk files are full project files with a lot more information in them than just the MIDI. In order to extract the MIDI information you would first have to open the files. Unfortunately this means you'd need either a version Cakewalk or Sonar.

The (perhaps) better news is that there's a [trial version](http://www.cakewalk.com/Products/SONAR/Web-Trial.aspx) of Sonar.
You should hopefully be able to open your files from there.

Comment: Bandlab now provide Cakewalk for free - you can open your .wrk files again!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the demo versions of Sonar no longer let you save or export. You can play your .WRK files, but not convert them.

I was able to convert my files using a DOS program found here: http://www.vgmpf.com/Wiki/index.php?title=Cake_to_MIDI

It works with FreeDOS. I used the FTP server instructions on the FreeDOS wiki to copy files to and from FreeDOS. See http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/VirtualBox_-_Chapter_6

A bit of a pain, but it worked for me.